Adding compile decency Koala Android Studio
Unfortunately upgraded to Koala Android studio and Gradle dependency has completely changed and I can not work out how to add a simple dependency like:
compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.0.3'

Where on earth does this now go? I put it where I would previously, build.gradle.kts (Module app) under the dependencies section...but they have all changed to implementation and 'compile' is not accepted.
Cannot find any clear documentation on this.
Any help please

Use implementation. Starting with Gradle 7.x, the “compile” configuration is no longer used directly. Instead, the “implementation” configuration is used for dependencies that are required for both compile and runtime.

Thanks. I thought that may be the case, but using:  implementation('com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.0.3') gives error: too many characters in literal line (red line under the url)

Furthermore, import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView in my Activity file also has error - unable to resolve symbol 'barteksc'. Why has this upgrade completely broke a working system...\

"too many characters in literal line" -- build.gradle.kts is in Kotlin. Strings in Kotlin use ", not ', as delimiters. "Why has this upgrade completely broke a working system" -- Gradle 7.0 introduced this change over four years ago.

Changed to "" (comment didn't reflect this, apologies). However I can not get this to compile. Using implementation getting error: failed to resolve com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.0.3 / also 2.8.2 / 3.1.0 etc

Only ran into this issue today...

Thank you to @Ken Wolf and @CommonsWare, managed to get the correct implementation syntax
However the issue remained until I changed the implementation url to: 'com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3'
Seems barteksc is no longer
